# Send two nodejs http requests, second relies on the first

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I need to get a token from a server using a username/password combo, then after I receive the token I need to send a second request using the token as the content of a header. So far this is what I have:

```
var requestData = {
    'username': 'myUser',
    'password': 'myPassword1234'
}

var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/login',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
}

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("Status: " + res.statusCode)
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let body = ""
    res.on('data', function (data) {
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("Success")
            body += data
        } else {
            invalidLogin()
        }
    })
    res.on('end', function () {
        body = JSON.parse(body)
        console.log("DONE")
        console.log(body)
        validLogin(body["token"])
    })
})
req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('error: ' + e.message)
})
req.write(JSON.stringify(requestData))
req.end()
```

And then in `validLogin()` (which is called in the first request), I have this:

```
function validLogin(token) {
console.log(token)

var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/dashboard',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': token,
    }
}

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("Status: " + res.statusCode)
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let body = ""
    res.on('data', function (data) {
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
            body += data
        } else {
            console.log(body)
        }
    })
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(body)
    })
})
req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('error: ' + e.message)
})
req.end()
}
```

The first request works and responds as expected, but the second request doesn't ever go. I know the function is being called because it prints to the console, but the request doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `request-promise` it makes chaining requests together very easy.  (Code not tested, but general gist is accurate)

```js
var rp = require('request-promise');

var options_login = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 8080,
  path: '/login',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  payload: JSON.stringify(requestData),
  json: true
};

var options_request = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/dashboard',
    method: 'GET',
    json: true
};

rp(options)
  .catch(function(parsedBody){
     console.log("Error logging in.");
  })
  .then(function(parsedBody) {
     options_request.headers = {
       'Authorization': parsedBody.token,
     };

     return rp(options_request);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Loading the dashboard failed...");
  });
```

Comment: I tried looking at your example and some others and it only sends the first request, it doesnt matter which request is first it only sends the first one. Do you know why this could be the case?